# Confused about the prime elements of a ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am having a difficult time verifying if I am correct. I am working on a [this released exam](https://math.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/pages/F05_Final_Exam-B.Samuels_0.pdf). This problem:
[image: Question I am working on]

1. Looking at this problem: [Prime elements of $\mathbb{Q}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/725769/prime-elements-of-mathbbq).
   I can rule out that any power of $2$ is a prime element of this ring as it is a unit. $2^k \times 2^{-k} = 1$.
2. I am pretty sure that that all integer primes except two are primes of this ring as well as all $p \times 2^{-1}$. I believe any greater powers of two would potentially violate the property iff $p \space | \space ab$ then $p \space | \space a$ or $p \space | \space b$.
3. I don't know if there are any further primes though, although I have a strong suspicion this is not a UFD if these are the only primes as a number like $7/4$ would be impossible to represent.

Am I correct? How can I confirm there are no further primes?

Comment: Here $2$ is a unit (invertible) so you ignore it in prime factorizations just like you ignore $-1$ in prime factorizations in $\,\Bbb Z.\ $ So prime factorizations are the same as in $\,\Bbb Z\,$ except you ignore $2$ since it has become a unit.

Comment: $R$ can be realized as the localization of $S = \{2, 4, 8, 16, \cdots\}$ in $\mathbb Z$. So $R$ is a UFD as $Z$ is a UFD (see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140584/about-the-localization-of-a-ufd)

Comment: @John Surely the OP would not be asking these questions if they knew about localization.

Comment: @BillDubuque : I agree that. But this comment is also for those who are interested in the general question (at least that is the reason I search that question).

Comment: @BillDubuque: When you say $2$ is a unit, are you referring to the $p \times 2^{-1}$ is unnecessary just as $-1$ is unnecessary in prime factorization?

Comment: @Bair $\ 2^n p\ $ is associate to $\,p\,$ just like $-p$ is associate to $p$ in  $\,\Bbb Z.\ $ From these infinitely many associates we can choose $\,p\,$ as the simplest rep, i.e. we can ignore the unit factors of $2.\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque: Ok, so then we can construct any numerator as a unique combination of primes (well known property of primes) and choose a specific bottom element as a particular unit so this would imply that R is a UFD then?

Comment: @Bair The unique prime factorization arises from that in $\,\Bbb Z\,$ by ignoring all factors of $2,\,$ both in numerator and denominator, literally erase them in factorizations.

Comment: @BillDubuque: Ok, thanks! It is just hard to wrap my head around. A lot of things in abstract algebra are requiring some serious rewiring of my brain. *sigh*